# Complex Import/Export Data Access/Excel

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

Our organisation has been given a spreadsheet template to do batch imports to a website.

It's quite a faff for users to update as it's structured all on a single page in the following way:

```
 |        A         |        B         |        C         |
1| ProvidersSection |                  |                  |
2| ProviderHeading1 | ProviderHeading2 | ProviderHeading3 |
3|   ProviderData1  |  ProviderData2   |   ProviderData3  |
4|   VenuesSection  |                  |                  |
5|  VenuesHeading1  |  VenuesHeading2  |  VenuesHeading3  |
6|    VenuesData1   |   VenuesData2    |    VenuesData3   |
7|   OpportSection  |                  |                  |
8|  OpportHeading1  |  OpportHeading2  |  OpportHeading3  |
9|    OpportData1   |   OpportData2    |    OpportData3   |
```

I don't know if that's clear, but basically it's 3 tables stacked on top of one another: Providers, Venues and Opportunities.

So for example, the Provider's table is denoted by the "ProvidersSection" text in A1, then in the row below that (row 2) is the column headings for the Providers table and then below that (row 3) is the data that corresponds to the provider table's column headings.

Each "data" part is not limited to the 1 row I've sketched in the above example though, so if there were 2 records for the providers table, the venues section would be pushed down to row 5 instead.

What I want to do is hold the data for this spreadsheet in 3 Access tables instead and use VBA to populate the spreadsheet in the format specified above.

I've done some VBA exporting before, but not quite to this kind of complexity, so I could do with some pointers, in particular:

- Is this best approached as Access VBA export to Excel or an Excel VBA import from Access?
- What method will allow me to specify an exact location in Excel to export data to?
- How can I ensure that the starting position of each table's data occurs after the last record of the table preceeding it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Either will do, depends on your own preferences... However if all other functionality around this data would sit in Access I would first consider putting this in Access as well.
2. You can directly refer to Ranges from your VBA code via Excel application object > Workbook object > Worksheet object > Range object
3. Create range objects that refer to those locations or have a counter keep track numerically (count the rows)